# SQL SSL errors when deploying laravel project to azure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, azure

I deployed the project to azure and both the webpage displays properly and links work fine, but for the user registration I need to connect the database.  Everything works well locally and I followed all the instructions of creating/connecting a sqsl db in azure but I get thte following 3 errors and not sure what to do, how to debug, its a project I was given to deply and didnt create myself,( I am only gona show the first 3 lines of the error since they are long):

UPDATE: It works if I disable the SSL on azure so its got something to do with my local app config for that

1-

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ***@***.com)

in Connection.php line 647
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ?', array('***@***.com'), object(Closure))
in Connection.php line 607
```

2-

```
(2/3) PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.

in PDOConnection.php line 50
at PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=***.mysql.database.azure.com;port=**+;dbname=uwiredb', '***@***', 'MySQLAzure2017', array(0, 2, 0, false, false))
in Connector.php line 65
at Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=***.mysql.database.azure.com;port=***;dbname=***', '***@***', 'MySQLAzure2017', array(0, 2, 0, false, false))
in Connector.php line 44
```

3-

```
(1/3) PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [9002] SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

here is the DB section of my .env file:

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=mydbserver.mysql.database.azure.com
    DB_DATABASE=mydb
    DB_USERNAME=myuser
    DB_PASSWORD=mypass
    MYSQL_SSL=true
```

And here is the connection part of my database.php file in the config folder, I know the hosts

```
 'connections' => [

'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
],

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
    'options' => (env('MYSQL_SSL')) ? [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => '/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem', 
    ] : [],
],

'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],

'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

],

I know the host is set to local but that is how I understood it should be from the azure docs that say:

```
You can use the PHP getenv method to access the settings. the Laravel code uses an env wrapper over the PHP getenv. For example, the MySQL configuration in config/database.php looks like the following code:

PHP

Copy
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    ...
],
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry I had thought of what to include in the post but forgot to add it all at the end, just updated with my .env and database.php file

Comment: Looks like you need to add the SSL options to your config to the database.php file. You will need the cert files from the database server. Then you need to reference these in the options for the connection on the app server.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong database.php, I had copied the project and pasted the new one by mistake.  I updated the post now you can see in the database.php it has the sslmode and options which declares to use a baltimoresecuritycert. which was what the azure docs said I had to put,   Is this what you mean??? the other stuff in the database.php like host and port under mysql I understood from the azure docs I leave like that even though they arent the deployment setting and the env writes over them is this correct?